# Where to find the logs for Lambda@Edge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-lambda-edge

As one of the steps for the [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083329/debugging-the-cloudfronts-problem-after-enabling-lambdaedge) I've faced, I need to see the logs for some Lambda@Edge but I cannot find them anywhere.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-testing-debugging.html) on Lambda@Edge:

> When you review CloudWatch log files or metrics when you're
>   troubleshooting errors, be aware that they are displayed or stored in
>   the Region closest to the location where the function executed. So, if
>   you have a website or web application with users in the United
>   Kingdom, and you have a Lambda function associated with your
>   distribution, for example, you must change the Region to view the
>   CloudWatch metrics or log files for the London AWS Region.

The lambda function I'm trying to find the logs for is located in `us-east-1` (mandated by CloudFront since it is used as a distribution's event handler) while I'm in Canada so I assume the closest region would be `ca-central-1`. But since I'm not developing in `ca-central-1`, I don't have any log groups in that region. In any case, I don't see the logs for my Lambda@Edge. For the sake of completeness, I checked all the regions and I couldn't find any trace of logs for the lambda function. To be clear, I'm looking for a log group with the lambda function's name.

I'm positive that there should be logs since I have `console.log()` in my code and also I can download the content requested (the lambda function is in charge of selecting the S3 bucket holding the contents) which means the lambda function was successfully executed. If it wasn't, I should have not been able to get the S3 content.

Where can I find the logs for my Lambda@Edge function?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For anyone else who might be facing the same issue, use the script mentioned in the same documentation page to find your log groups:

```
FUNCTION_NAME=function_name_without_qualifiers
for region in $(aws --output text  ec2 describe-regions | cut -f 4) 
do
    for loggroup in $(aws --output text  logs describe-log-groups --log-group-name "/aws/lambda/us-east-1.$FUNCTION_NAME" --region $region --query 'logGroups[].logGroupName')
    do
        echo $region $loggroup
    done
done
```

Create a file, paste the above script in it, replace the `function_name_without_qualifiers` with your function's name, make it executable and run it. It will find you the regions and log groups for your Lambda@Edge. The lesson learnt here is that the log group is not named like ordinary log groups. Instead it follows this structure:

```
/aws/lambda/${region}.${function_name}
```

Comment: CloudFront had two layers of edges -- the outer "global" edges and the inner "regional" edges. Cache misses go from global to regional to origin, and Lambda@Edge functions typically run -- and log -- in the region of the [regional edge](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/#edge-locations) nearest the viewer.  Testing suggests you should find these typically go to either us-east-1 or us-east-2 due to their proximity to Canada, even though the function is actually declared in us-east-1.  It gets replicated to all the others.

Comment: Note the format of the output data from describe-regions has changed and you now need to `cut -f 4`

Comment: Tiny script based on this answer: https://github.com/walkermatt/dotbin/blob/50df03e61a81861c863dbbc0b3bf73fdb0ce1a6e/find-lambda-edge-logs

Comment: Hi @walkermatt, I am getting below error while running the script.

 ' doesn't match a supported format.                                                
 
 An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the
 DescribeLogGroups operation: 1 validation error detected: Value
 'C:/Users/x0120370/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/aws/lambda/sigv4-request-to-s3'
 at 'logGroupNamePrefix' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must
 satisfy regular expression pattern: [\.\-_/#A-Za-z0-9]+

Comment: @KiranPatil it looks as though you are using WSL given the file path, I've only tested on Linux/ Bash. I'd expect the script to be called like so:

`./find-lambda-edge-logs sigv4-request-to-s3`

Comment: I found logs in my region from where I logged in to AWS account.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the format of `log describe-log-groups` has also changed. When I tryed the script, it returned nothing. But with "/aws/lambda/$FUNCTION_NAME" instead of "/aws/lambda/us-east-1.$FUNCTION_NAME" the script returns the list of group with the following structure:

```
${region} /aws/lambda/${function_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Last but not least would be good to check Lambda's role permissions.

In my case that was the problem, because by default it allowed writing logs only to 1 region (us-east-1).

Here is how my policy looks like now:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:{account-id}:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:{account-id}:log-group:/aws/lambda/{function-name}:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

*`{account-id}` - your AWS Account ID*